# Setup rightBarButtonItem in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have stuck on this bug for days. I have a problem with rightBarButtonItem. I want to create a custom view. Inside custom view, there are 2 items: label, imageView. When I type this:

```
let customView = UIView()
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.backgroundColor = .black
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 40)

    let coinLabelNavigationBar = UILabel()
    coinLabelNavigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25)
    coinLabelNavigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coinLabelNavigationBar.text = "200"
    coinLabelNavigationBar.font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText-Medium", size: 20)
    coinLabelNavigationBar.textColor = UIColor.white

    let coinImage = UIImageView()
    coinImage.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
    coinImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coinImage.image = UIImage(named: "Coin")

    customView.addSubview(coinLabelNavigationBar)
    customView.addSubview(coinImage)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

It doesn't work, navigationBar shows me this:
[image: NavBar]

Do you have any idea, how to fix it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you show me image that describe how you want to display you bar button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
let customView = UIView()
//        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.backgroundColor = .black
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 40)

    let coinLabelNavigationBar = UILabel()
    coinLabelNavigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25)
//        coinLabelNavigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coinLabelNavigationBar.text = "200"
    coinLabelNavigationBar.font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText-Medium", size: 20)
    coinLabelNavigationBar.textColor = UIColor.white

    let coinImage = UIImageView()
    coinImage.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
 //        coinImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coinImage.image = UIImage(named: "coin.jpg")

    customView.addSubview(coinLabelNavigationBar)
    customView.addSubview(coinImage)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0:

```
let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName), for: .touchUpInside)
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)  

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1,item2], animated: true)
```